Pong ball slowing down on contact instead of speeding up
So I was following a simple pong guide to kinda ease myself into coding and it was all going fine until the person added code to speed up everytime the ball came in contact with everything, except for me it was slowing down, I can't seem to find the problem though so I came here incase anyone else could figure it out. Though it may be part of unity and programming which I can find out.
using UnityEngine;

public class Bouncy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float bounceStrength;

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        Ball ball = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Ball>();

        if (ball != null)
        {
            Vector2 normal = collision.GetContact(0).normal;
            ball.AddForce(-normal * this.bounceStrength);
        }
    }
}


I thought it might've been the (-normal)
ball.AddForce(-normal * this.bounceStrength);

but changing it didn't really make a difference.
Looking at other questions it doesn't seem like they used the same code and most answers were about drag which isn't that problem.

Id agree the -normal sounds like the likely answer, while drag and friction wont help, you could do something with the collisionexit, and add a small amount to its velocity, as it will be at the right angle, you just want to add to the speed

@BugFinder Turns out it was something with the components. I had put the bounce material in both the box collider AND the rigid body which must've messed with it, I couldn't remove the material and it didn't seem like any harm so I just left it.
